# Why viewController pops to rootViewController unexpectedly?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am pushing `ChatViewController` from TraderDetailTableViewController on the navigation stack, but when the default back button is touched in `ChatViewController`, it pops to `ServicesTableViewController`, rather than to the `TraderDetailTableViewController` as I was expecting.
All other controllers are linked via segues, except  `ChatViewController` which is instantiated.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
UITabBarController
  NavigationController
    ServicesTableViewController
      TraderListTableViewController
         TraderDetailTableViewController
             ChatViewController 


func startChat() {
     let chatVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") as! ChatViewController
        chatVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: what pop code share it

Comment: I only press the default back button in `ChatViewController`. Is it not normal to pop to the parent Viewcontroller from which it was pushed? namely to `TraderDetailTableViewController`

Comment: Never mind, I had attached a gesture recognizer by mistake on the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` in `ChatViewController`  and I had forgotten about it.

Answer (score -1):

I have a some problem like your problem. I sort out using this reference. [Programmatic Navigation View Controllers in Swift](https://makeapppie.com/2014/09/15/swift-swift-programmatic-navigation-view-controllers-in-swift/)

Comment: Could you be more specific? This should probably be a comment, not an answer.